# Adding custom tag in message node in Android Smack 4.2

Tags: java, android, xmpp, smack

I have implemented the [Smack](https://github.com/igniterealtime/Smack) for one to one chat in my Android App.

Now i have a **requirement** to send the message in the following format:

```
<message id="783475-35345-35-345-353" from="xyz@x.com" type="chat" to="abc@x.com" nick="james"><body>Hello</body></message>
```

But so far **my message** looks like below:

```
<message id="783475-35345-35-345-353" from="xyz@x.com" type="chat" to="abc@x.com" ><body>Hello</body></message>
```

Below is my code:

```
Message message = new Message();
message.setStanzaId(UUID.randomUUID().toString()); 
message.setType(Message.Type.chat);
message.setBody(textToSend.getText().toString());
message.setTo(chat.getXmppAddressOfChatPartner());
message.setFrom(ownJid);
```

**I could not find a way to add the custom tag "nick" in the "message" node**. Can someone please **help** me with it. I tried the extension provided by the Smack but they all add an extra node but not a tag in the existing node.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend using custom top level stanza attributes. And Smack does not support it. There is an incomplete PR at https://github.com/igniterealtime/Smack/pull/69 which would add support thought.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply.. i am checking.. Mean while could you please add sample code for adding custom attribute in message using your PR.